# Document.write method

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to make a JS action where it should display the selected items from the list, I can only select one but I want to select more than one and view it in a list

```html
<body>
  <label for="issue">Issue Type:</label>

  <select multiple="multiple" name="issue" id="issue">
    <option value="passport">passport</option>
    <option value="selfie">selfie</option>
    <option value="nationalId">nationalId</option>

  </select>

  <p> you are missing the following information:</p>
  <ul id="issue-type">
    <script>
      var output = '';
      let issues = document.getElementById("issue");
      for (i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
        output += document.write("<li>" + issues[i].text + </li>").innerHTML = issues;
      }
    </script>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: document.write replaces the content of the page. There are better options. It also makes no sense you are storing what document.write returns and adding it to a string.

Comment: @epascarello so, i what do you recomend using instide of document.write?

Comment: innerHTML, createElement, etc. Plenty of ways to add content to the DOM. You also have no event listener so you are not waiting for the user to select anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution and I commented each line.

```js
let output = '';
let issues = document.querySelector("#issue");
let issue_types = document.querySelector("#issue-type");

issues.addEventListener("change", function(e) { //change event listener to check for when the select is changed
  issue_types.innerHTML = ""; //empties destination div
  let options = e.target.selectedOptions; //grabs the selected options
  options = Array.from(options).map(({ value }) => value); //converts the selected options to an array of values
  options.forEach(function(opt){ //loops through the options
    let li = document.createElement("li"); //creates a LI element
    li.innerHTML = opt; //sets the innerHTML of the list item to the option
    issue_types.appendChild(li) //appends the list to the destination UL
  });
});
```

```html
<label for="issue">Issue Type:</label>

  <select multiple="multiple" name="issue" id="issue">
    <option value="passport">passport</option>
    <option value="selfie">selfie</option>
    <option value="nationalId">nationalId</option>

  </select>

  <p> you are missing the following information:</p>
  <ul id="issue-type">
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an event listener to listen for a change of selection and you need to update the html of the element. You rarely ever want to use document.write in an application.

```js
const issueSelect = document.getElementById("issue");
// listen for a change
issueSelect.addEventListener("change", selChanged);

function selChanged() {
  var output = '';
  let issues = issueSelect.options;
  // loop over the options
  for (var i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
    // is it selected?
    if (issues[i].selected) {
      // yes, build a list item
      output += "<li>" + issues[i].value + "</li>";
    }
  }
  // set the list's content
  document.getElementById("issue-type").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <label for="issue">Issue Type:</label>

  <select multiple="multiple" name="issue" id="issue">
    <option value="passport">passport</option>
    <option value="selfie">selfie</option>
    <option value="nationalId">nationalId</option>

  </select>

  <p> you are missing the following information:</p>
  <ul id="issue-type">

  </ul>


</body>
```

How I would have coded it

```js
const issueSelect = document.getElementById("issue");
// listen for a change
issueSelect.addEventListener("change", selChanged);

function selChanged() {
  const selectedOpts = issueSelect.querySelectorAll("option:checked");
  const output = [...selectedOpts].map(opt => `<li>${opt.value}</li>`).join('');
  document.getElementById("issue-type").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <label for="issue">Issue Type:</label>

  <select multiple="multiple" name="issue" id="issue">
    <option value="passport">passport</option>
    <option value="selfie">selfie</option>
    <option value="nationalId">nationalId</option>

  </select>

  <p> you are missing the following information:</p>
  <ul id="issue-type">

  </ul>


</body>
```

Comment: Okay,I have another question, can't I write the JS inside the <ul> tag ?

Comment: No clue what you mean by that

Comment: I prefer this answer because it does not change the "dialect" of Javascript used. @imvain2's answer uses modern structures such as Array.forEach() but changing to that type of loop just complicates sorting out where there errors were in the original script.

Comment: @mbt When you write JS in the the <ul> tag it runs immediately upon the page loading not giving the user the opportunity to select anything in the select object. Using the .addEventListener('change') lets the user select something before creating the list.

Comment: @mbt, you can certainly put your script inside of the UL (the event handler will still be ran as long as its BELOW the select element itself). However, its generally bad practice and getting used to separating your HTML from the JS will allow you to combine in external scripts and others.